# Why my dropdown is so slow to update second dependent dropdown in webapp from google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have around 50 data in 1stselection, a few on 2nd selection. Here is my full code.
My problem is especially the first item selection in 1st selection options. it's annoyingly slow to update the second selection options when 1st item is selected.

gs code:

```
function get1st() {

var ss = getSS();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data'); 
var range  = sheet.getRange("A2:A");//or "A2:A" for all data
var vA  = range.getValues();
var dataSize = vA.length;
var options = [];
Logger.log("array size="+ dataSize);
for(let i=2;i<range.getLastRow();i++){
  if(options.indexOf(val = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue())===-1){
    options.push(val);
  }
  
}
// var dataArray = values.toString().split(",");
// var stringVal = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
// Logger.log(stringVal);
// return JSON.stringify(stringVal); //Modified
Logger.log(options);
return options;
```

}

```
function get2nd(first='X60') {

var ss = getSS();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data'); 
var range  = sheet.getRange("A2:A");//or "A2:A" for all data
var vA  = range.getValues();
var dataSize = vA.length;
var options = [];
Logger.log("array size="+ dataSize);
for(let i=2;i<range.getLastRow();i++){
  if(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() === first){
    if(options.indexOf(val = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue())===-1){
    options.push(val);
  }
  }
  
}
// var dataArray = values.toString().split(",");
// var stringVal = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
// Logger.log(stringVal);
// return JSON.stringify(stringVal); //Modified
Logger.log(options);
return options;
```

}

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<script>
    async function  AddList() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    List.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select State";
    option.selected =true;
    List.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      List.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).get1st();

    // google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(error) {
    //   alert("This action failed to complete. Error: "+ error);
    //  }.getCountry();

    };


  window.onload = function() {

  AddList();
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <label for="List">Country<label>
    <select id="List" name="List"  onclick="SecondSelect(this.value)" required ></select>
  </div>     
  <div>
    <label for="list2">State<label>
    <select id="list2" name="list2" required></select>
  </div>     
</form>

      <a href="#" id="tButton1">click me</a>
      <a href="#" id="tButton2">click me I have a parameter</a>
    <script>
    

        // document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);
        // window.addEventListener("load", pageFullyLoaded, false);
        // function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
        //     alert("haha DOM content is loaded");
        // }

        // function pageFullyLoaded(e){
        //    alert("haha page fully loaded");
        //   document.getElementbyId("tButton1").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
        //   document.getElementbyId("tButton2").onclick = function(){sayHi("Hi")};

        //   function myFunction(){
        //     alert("my Function is called");
        //   }

        //   function sayHi(msg){
        //     alert(msg);
        //   }

        // }

    
    function  SecondSelect(country) {
      var country = document.getElementById("List");
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
    {

    console.log(ar);
    
    list2.length = 0;
    
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select State";
    option.selected =true;
    list2.appendChild(option);
    
    ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      list2.appendChild(option);    
    });
    
    }).get2nd(country.value);

    // google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(error) {
    //   alert("This action failed to complete. Error: "+ error);
    //  }.getCountry();

    };

    </script>     
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="cart_Test.js"> </script> -->
   
  

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main problem is it's slow. Though after few clicks options are showing correctly.

Comment: You should avoid the use of ranges like `"A2:A"` because often return a lot trailing nulls between getLastRow() and getMaxRows().  `getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1)` is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

This function does the same thing only it gets all of the required data at one time and uses it from vA rather than running getValue() from inside the loop

```
function get2nd(first = 'X60') {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,2);//returning first two columns rather than using getValue() to get them from inside the loop
  var vA = range.getValues();
  var options = [];
  vA.forEach(r=>{
    if(r[0]==first && !~options.indexOf(r[1])) {
      options.push(r[1]);
    }
  }) 
  Logger.log(options);
  return options;
}
```

You might find it valuable to read [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

[bit wise not ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: I have used your solution. It is easier for me to understand. But one problem I am facing now is on the android chrome browser, I have to select twice from an item from 1st selection then only the 2nd selection options are updated. Surprisingly, this never the case in my laptop or PC. why is that I have clue?

Comment: Youtube screen recording [link](https://youtu.be/_PQKdi6TTT4)

Comment: Sorry I don't have Android devices so I'm of no help in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still trying to figure out why the dropdown item has to tap twice, and sometimes tap another item, and then tap again the item I want from the selection list. Then 2nd item list is updated. This problem is in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

### Modification points:

- In your script, `getValue()` is used in the for loop in the functions `get1st` and `get2nd`. In this case, the process cost will become high. This has already been mentioned by the existing answer. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995298)
- In your situation, when the cell values are not changed while selecting the value between the 1st dropdown list and 2nd dropdown list, how about retrieving all values from the columns "A" and "B" from Spreadsheet at `get1st()`? By this, when the 2nd dropdown list is selected, the values for 2nd dropdown list can be put without using `google.script.run`. I thought that when the number of use of `google.script.run` is reduced, the process cost will be able to be reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Google Apps Script side:

In this case, one function of `getValues()` is used instead of `get1st()` and `get2nd()`.

```
function getValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  return sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
}
```

### Javascript side:

Please modify your functions of `AddList` and `SecondSelect` as follows.

#### `AddList()`

```
let values = [];  // Added

function AddList() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
    values = ar;  // Added
    List.length = 0;
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "";
    option.text = "Select State";
    option.selected = true;
    List.appendChild(option);
    [...new Set(values.map(([a]) => a))]  // Modified
    .forEach(a => {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = a;
      option.text = a;
      List.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getValues();
}

window.onload = function() {
  AddList();
}
```

#### `SecondSelect()`

```
function SecondSelect(country) {
  var country = document.getElementById("List");
  list2.length = 0;
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "";
  option.text = "Select State";
  option.selected = true;
  list2.appendChild(option);
  var v = country.value || 'X60';
  [...new Set(values.filter(([a]) => a == v).map(([,b]) => b))]  // Modified
  .forEach(function(item, index) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item;
    option.text = item;
    list2.appendChild(option);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can someone guide me parameter of the SecondSelect function. country is used where and how?

Comment: I was hesitant to use the code @Tanaike suggested but when really have gone through I can see difference in speed in google chrome browser in my PC. bud sadly something is not right in android chrome browser. second list is not updating after I select first element from the first list. This is Only the first element that cuases most problem.

Comment: finally going with two list merged into one by concatenating values 'var dataRow = values.map(row => { return row[0] + " : "+ row[1]});
    console.log("datarow "+ dataRow);
    dataRow.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {    
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = item;
      option.text = item;
      List.appendChild(option);    
    });'

Comment: @k.b Thank you for replying. At first, I deeply apologize for `I was hesitant to use the code`. And also , I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for replying. I have removed the 2nd drop-down selection element altogether because, in mobile devices (android & ios), the 2nd selection was behaving weirdly ( I had to click/tap 2-3 times, switch options in 1st selection to update the 2nd selection options). I could not find any solution for this. Because my client could not wait any more, we decided to concatenate the 1st & 2nd options together and give only one drop-down. That's what I have replied in my previous message.

Comment: @k.b Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your current situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanike You have helped me - by your efforts and codes.No apology please.

Comment: @k.b Thank you for replying. I would like to study more and try to understand about your current issue. When I could correctly understand it and found the solution, I would like to tell you here.